# Capture multiple repetitive group in regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm using `/{(\w+)\s+((\w+="\w+")\s*)+/` pattern to capture all attributes.
The problem is that it matches the input but can't group attribute one by one and just groups the last attribute.

```
[person name="Jackson" family="Smith"]
```

or

```
[car brand="Benz" type="SUV"]
```

Comment: Your regex pattern won't match the input you gave.  Please add a problem description to your question.

Comment: Wait a second, are there always two attributes or might there be 1 or more?  What is the exact desired result? Do you need the tag name?  Is the goal to validate, extract, or validate&extract?  What is the whole input string? Is there extra text before/after the tag to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

The `\G` ([continue](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)) metacharacter is the hero to call upon here.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/T2JmY))  ([Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxtLFD/1))

```
$tag = '[person name="Jackson" family="Smith"]';

var_export(preg_match_all('~(?:\G|\[\w+) (\w+)="(\w+)"~', $tag, $out) ? array_combine($out[1], $out[2]) : []);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'name' => 'Jackson',
  'family' => 'Smith',
)
```

---

If you need to pool the attributes&values with the tag name, only one loop is necessary for this too.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CO1PD))

```
$text = 'some text [person name="Jackson" family="Smith"] text [vehicle brand="Benz" type="SUV" doors="4" seats="7"]';

foreach (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^)|\[(\w+)) (\w+)="(\w+)"~', $text, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER) ? $out : [] as $matches) {
    if ($matches[1]) {
        $tag = $matches[1];  // cache the tag name for reuse with subsequent attr/val pairs
    }
    $result[$tag][$matches[2]] = $matches[3];
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'person' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Jackson',
    'family' => 'Smith',
  ),
  'vehicle' => 
  array (
    'brand' => 'Benz',
    'type' => 'SUV',
    'doors' => '4',
    'seats' => '7',
  ),
)
```

---

Due to the concerns of @Thefourthbird and @Jan, I have included a lookahead to match the closing square brace.  I have also built in accommodation for the possibility of zero attributes in the tag.  If given more time (sorry, don't have more), I could probably refine the following snippet to be slightly cleaner, but I believe I am accurately validating and extracting.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A13k5))

```
$text = 'some text [person name="Jackson" family="Smith"] text [vehicle brand="Benz" type="SUV" doors="4" seats="7"] and [invalid closed="false" monkeywrench [lonetag] text [single gender="female"]';

foreach (preg_match_all('~\[(\w+)(?=(?: \w+="\w+")*])(]?)|(?:\G(?!^) (\w+)="(\w+)")~', $text, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER) ? $out : [] as $matches) {
    if ($matches[2]) {
        $result[$matches[1]] = [];
    } elseif (!isset($matches[3])) {
        $tag = $matches[1];
    } else {
        $result[$tag][$matches[3]] = $matches[4];
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'person' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Jackson',
    'family' => 'Smith',
  ),
  'vehicle' => 
  array (
    'brand' => 'Benz',
    'type' => 'SUV',
    'doors' => '4',
    'seats' => '7',
  ),
  'lonetag' => 
  array (
  ),
  'single' => 
  array (
    'gender' => 'female',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Not required but perhaps to make sure there is also a closing `]` you might add a positive lookahead at the end `(?=[^]]*\])` +1

Comment: Fair enough, please review and let me know if you spot an inaccuracy.

Comment: Looks good, nice addition. I think you might even omit the `(]?)`

Comment: ...I was using that for grouping the output data.  If the desired result is clarified, perhaps I can adjust the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `\[\S+ ((?:[^"]+"){2}) ((?:[^"]+"){2})\]`

Explanation:

`\[` - match `[` literallly

`\S+` - mach one or more of non-whitespace characters

`(?...)` - non-capturing group

`[^"]+"` - match one or more characters other from `"` and repeat pattern two times due to `{2}`

`\]` - match `]` literally

In first capturing group will be your first attribute, in second there will be the second attribute.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZt1IN/1)

Answer (score 0):

Better use **two** expressions (or a parser altogether) instead. Consider the following:

```
<?php

$junk = <<<END
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
[person name="Jackson" family="Smith"]
lorem ipsum
[car brand="Benz" type="SUV"]

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
END;

$tag = "~\[(?P<tag>\w+)[^][]*\]~";
$key_values = '~(?P<key>\w+)="(?P<value>[^"]*)"~';

preg_match_all($tag, $junk, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo "Name: {$match["tag"]}\n";

    preg_match_all($key_values, $match[0], $attributes, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    print_r($attributes);
}
?>
```

Here we have

```
\[(?P<tag>\w+)[^][]*\]
```

for likely tags and

```
(?P<key>\w+)="(?P<value>[^"]*)"
```

for key/value pairs. The rest is a foreach loop.